# Why does not this thread stop in this situation?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me

I started a new thread to upload photos from the phone mobile to a computer webserver.

```
if (CMenu.retCommand == transferer)
{
     thrdTrsfr = new Thread(this);
     thrdTrsfr.start();
}

public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread() == thrdTrsfr)
        {
            if (vButtonPhotos.size() > 0)
                transfererPhotos("http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/photoj2meupload/uploadphoto.php");
            else
                afficheAlert("Aucune photo à transférer !");
        }
    }
```

When the upload is finished then I stopped the thread. I tested the number of active threads before the upload. When I tested the number of running threads after stopping the upload thread, the number does not change. I must navigate back to the main screen then the number of active thread is the same at before the upload. I use this code to stop the upload thread :

```
if (thrdTrsfr != null && thrdTrsfr.isAlive())
{
    thrdTrsfr.interrupt();
    thrdTrsfr = null;
}
```

So why must I go to the main screen in order to get the thread stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that `transfererPhotos()` is not finishing, perhaps due to waiting for an IO read of bytes that never arrives? If so, then the thread will stay alive forever, or until interrupted (as you are doing).

BTW, I can't see any value to the test for current thread:

```
if (Thread.currentThread() == thrdTrsfr) // Huh?
```

Comment: Yes there was an InputStream opened not closed !

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Thread.interrupt()` does not kill a thread.  It is more like asking the thread politely if it could stop now.

- If the thread checks with `Thread.isInterrupted()`, it can see that it has been interrupted.
- If the thread is in a `sleep` or `wait` call, the call will terminate with an `InterruptedException`.
- Under some circumstances, a thread doing an IO operation *might* have the call terminated with an `InterruptedIOException`.  (I've never been able to figure out whether this actually happens with modern JVMs, or whether this is just a legacy exception ...)

If none of the above happens, an interrupted thread will just keep running as if nothing has happened.

---

In your case:

- the `interrupt()` may not be noticed (as above),
- your application (or some library) is catching and ignoring the interrupt, or
- there is a race condition and you are testing to see if the thread has died before it has had a chance to deal with the interrupt.

Comment: I use java j2me but not java j2se. So the method isInterrupted() is not available in j2me.

Comment: The method is available, but it does not stop the Thread like you assumed. The best way to stop a Thread is to let the Runnable return from its run method. If you need to initiate termination from another Thread you can add a field like 'boolean terminationRequested' in the Runnable and set it to true from the other Thread. Then make sure the field is checked regularly and return from the run method when it is true.

Comment: How to return from the run method ?

Comment: @Andy Frédéric - the same way that you return from *any* method call.

Answer (score 0):

If your code checks thread count (by using `activeCount()`) right after the following:

```
thrdTrsfr.interrupt();
thrdTrsfr = null;
```

In that case, the thread is probably not killed yet, when `activeCount()` is called.

Try to add `join()` call after the `interrupt()` call. Then you can be sure that thread is really dead, when `activeCount()` is called.

So, replace above code with the following:

```
thrdTrsfr.interrupt();
thrdTrsfr.join();
thrdTrsfr = null;
```

Comment: even if I added the join() method ( and I caught the InterruptedException ) , the thread is not stopped : I cannot do something else such as deleting the photo stored inside the phone : I got an IOException. Although when I do not start the upload-thread then I can successfully delete the photo. So what should I do in order to delete the photo after uploading the photo ?

Comment: If join() returns, then the thread is stopped. If activeCount() still shows extra thread, then problem is somewhere else. Does the methdod call transfererPhotos() create a second thread?